# Is it possible to find the most voted answers?

Tags: support

I found a button to find the most voted questions, is there a way to find the most voted answers?
Thanks

Comment: For starters, [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/great-answer) is a list of 100+ vote answers.

Comment: There was a recent question about this on Meta.SE, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 4):

Quite easily with data.SE.

I've composed a [query here](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/291096/highest-voted-answers) for you (and others interested I suppose).

You can enter in the number of answers you want returned with the numAnswers variable. For example, numAnswers=10 will give you the top 10 highest voted answers.

You can also switch the site to query so you can find the top answers on whichever site you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use search for this:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer

There's more help on the search operators in the search page (click on "Advanced Search") or in the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/searching).