# How can I find the highest scored posts of all tags?

Tags: support, search, up-votes

I like to read the highest scored posts in the PSE. If I watch posts under a specific tag, I can find a tab which sorts posts by votes, under *that tag*. For instance, if I choose the tag [newtonian-mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newtonian-mechanics), I can find the highest scored posts under [newtonian-mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newtonian-mechanics). Though on the home page, which contains *all questions*, there is no tab called 'votes'. Is there a way to find the highest scored posts, regardless of the tag, without searching for each tag?

Comment: Do you want ***one*** result (the question/post with the highest score for the entire site) or ***several*** (the highest scoring question/post for each tag)?

Comment: Qmechanic has already given what I was looking for. But I don't know how to view the highest scored post for the *entire site*. Is there a method?

Comment: To view all questions and answers in one long list, searching [is:](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3A) seems to do the trick. You can then sort by votes.

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6616/149907

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the most up-voted question type [is:q](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq) in the SE search engine, and click [votes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq).

Similarly, for the most up-voted answer, type [is:a](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa).